# How to switch off OS X word suggestions?

Tags: macos, safari, osx-mavericks

It is very annoying that every time Macbook keeps changing our vernacular-words typed in english into  something else.. like this

[image]

Especially working/chatting in Safari browser.

Can anyone tell me, how to switch off that temporarily..?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Under **System Preferences** -> **Keyboard** -> **Text** -> **Correct spelling automatically**